# Disfunctioning anchor jump

Tags: html, css, anchor

The anchor jump to `home` when I click the "home" button is not working, here's my code:

```html
<header>
    <div id="header_container">
        <div class="menuLogo">
            <img id="logo" />
        </div>
        <a href="#home"><div class="menuItem">Home</div></a>
        <div class="menuItem">Over</div>
        <div class="menuItem">Contact</div>
        <div id="mobile_menu_button"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="body_container">
    <div id="banner_container">
        <img id="banner" />
    </div>
    <div name="home" id="content_container">
        <div id="home_container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background: rgb(223,227,238);
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    min-width: 100%;
    background: rgb(50,50,50);
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#header_container {
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
}

#header_container div {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}

#logo {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

.menuItem {
    padding-top: 29px;
    height: calc(100% - 29px);
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Signika;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(203,207,218);
}

.menuItem:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(59,89,202);
    height: calc(100% - 33px);
    color: rgb(160,170,218);
}

.menuLogo {
    padding-top: 14.5px;
    height: calc(100% - 14.5px);
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#mobile_menu_button {
    display: none;
}

#body_container {
    padding-top: 80px;
}

#banner_container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#banner {
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
}

#content_container {
    background: rgb(235,235,240);
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
}

#home_container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

And a representative [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/vsbh6udp/2/)

Comment: There is no anchor in your HTML. You're missing an `<a href="#home">...</a>` somwhere.

Comment: @Jester Oh my how did I miss that... I added a href to the div but that of course doesn't work. Thanks, problem solved.

Comment: @Jester Never mind, problem not solved. It still doesn't scoll after adding a `<a></a>` to the div. See question for updated html.

Comment: `<a><div href="#home">` is just nonsense. Divs can't have a href attribute. It should be in the `<a>` tag. (And the closing `</a>` is missing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchors work with ids. If you want an anchors to make you jump to home, you must add an `id="home"` on something and not `name="home"`!

So change your div to

```
<div id="home">
```

instead of

```
<div name="home">
```